# invoke-oracle: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion

Tags: c++

So I get this error

```
invoke-oracle: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Abort (core dumped)
```

When the program runs this function

```
int  bloom_filter(int *filter,const  char *word, int num, int hnum){
uint64_t *hash;
printf("Using bloom_filter \n");
hash = (uint64_t *) malloc(hnum*sizeof(uint64_t));

int i,j, count =0;
 for (i =0; i < hnum; i++){
  hash[i] = hash_by(i,word);
  j = hash[i] % num;

  if(filter[j]== 1)
  count++;
  else
  filter[j] = 1;
 }
if (count == hnum)
return 1;
else
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have heap corruption - try stepping through this function in your debugger to see what is happening to `i` and `j` and/or run your code under valgrind to catch the heap corruption if it's happening earlier than this.

Comment: Make sure that `hash_by` returns something valid.

Comment: I tried running it while putting a printf right after 'hash = (uint64_t *) malloc(hnum*sizeof(uint64_t));"
And it didn't appear so I assume it has something to do with malloc.

Comment: Is this happening the first time the function is called?  I ask because I do not see a call to `free()` for `hash` so you have a memory leak.

Comment: Yes it happens the first time the function is called.

Comment: @GeoHa Then something you did before calling this function has caused the corruption. Common causes include indexing outside a dynamically allocated array or using a dynamically allocated object after it has been destroyed.

Comment: Yeah apparently there was a problem with a function before that, that was also using malloc after fixing it this issue also got fixed.